# Subtract 3 Months from Date

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to subtract 3 Months from 31st Dec 2019. I am trying below but i am getting "NA" as output(Not sure what's wrong i am doing.

```
library(lubridate)
Current.Date = as.Date("31-12-2019", "%d-%m-%Y")
print(Current.Date-months(3)
```

Comment: `Current.Date %m-% months(3)`

Comment: Thank @Rounak, it worked